# Mocked method claims it has more calls than expected

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I have a class, `QueryBuilder`, which sends the message `build` to an instance of another class, `Query`. The method that sends that message is called `build_query`. For the purpose of this question, I'm only concerned with what values `QueryBuilder` sends to `Query`'s `build` method.

My test for `QueryBuilder` asserts that `Query`'s `build` method is called once for each set of "grouped params" sorted by `QueryBuilder`.

```
def test_groups_queries_based_on_config(self):
    params = {'metatag_attr': 'name', 'metatag_val': 'description', 'robots': True}
    with patch.object(Query, 'build') as mock_query_build:
        self.query_builder.build_queries(params)
        calls = [call({'metatag_attr': 'name', 'metatag_val': 'description'}),
                 call({'robots': True})]
        mock_query_build.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

Here is the code for `QueryBuilder`.

```
class QueryBuilder(object):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        self._queries = []
        self._collected_params = None
        self._config = config or {}

    ...

    def build_queries(self, params):
        # should return an iterator of built queries
        self._collected_params = params
        for param_set in self._group_params():
            query = self.build_query(param_set)
            self._append_query(query)
        return self._queries

    def build_query(self, param_set):
        query = self._new_query()
        return query.build(param_set)

    ### Private ###
    def _new_query(self):
        return Query(shortcuts=self.shortcuts, option_groups=self.options)

    def _append_query(self, query):
        valid_query = {k: v for k, v in query.items() if not k == 'seo_attr'}
        if not valid_query:
            return
        self._queries.append(query)

    def _group_params(self):
        # initialize list to collect all params
        grouped_params = []
        # add the option params to the list
        options = self._get_options()
        grouped_params.extend(options)
        # add the shortcut params to the list
        shortcuts = self._get_shortcuts()
        grouped_params.extend(shortcuts)
        return grouped_params

    ...
```

Some private methods and public properties have been left out because I don't believe they pertain to the question.

The issue is that after I added this line to `QueryBuilder`'s private `_append_query` method...

```
valid_query = {k: v for k, v in query.items() if not k == 'seo_attr'}
if not valid_query:
    return
```

...I'm now getting several extra calls to the `build` method, causing my test to fail. These are the extra calls to `build`:

```
E       Expected: [call({'metatag_val': 'description', 'metatag_attr': 'name'}), call({'robots': True})]
E       Actual: [call({'metatag_val': 'description', 'metatag_attr': 'name'}),
E       call().items(),
E       call().items().__iter__(),
E       call({'robots': True}),
E       call().items(),
E       call().items().__iter__()]
```

I don't see how sending `items` to `query` in the dict comprehension is treated as a call to `build` again. What would explain this?